# Scraping AWS with Puppeteer runs locally but fails on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-scraping, puppeteer, vpn

I know it sounds a lot like other issues here in Stackoverflow, bear with me, it's not (not that I could tell)

I have a scraping app (using Puppeteer) that I use to scrape an Amazon public page.
It works great, I've debugged it by setting the `headless: false` and I see it works, and it gives me back the expected result.

The same app fails on Heroku, but the problem is not with launching or using Puppeteer (I have several indications), but probably because I'm being identified as a robot.
The error returned is:
`` waiting for selector `#link_continue input` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded ``
Important to say that the error is a generic Puppeteer error that indicates that the selector I'm waiting for just doesn't appear on-page.
I know it should as it's a selector on the first page I navigate to, and it works locally (as mentioned before) - the selector always exists if the page loads.

I had **the exactly same error** when I've tried to run the scraping on my local machine before setting a User-Agent header. But at that time I could use the `headless:false` so I saw in my eyes that I'm being rejected due to illegal operations on their page (robots-like operations) so I was redirected to an error page that didn't contain this selector on it.

For this reason, I suspect it recognizes me as a robot, but I don't know how to debug it, it drives me crazy.

Now, if you'd like to reproduce the problem:
You need to wait for the mentioned selector on this site:
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index
and then deploy it to Heroku and try to run it maybe 2-3 times

** Two questions: **

1. How can I proceed from here, I'm 99.9% sure it's the same issue I had previously, but I can't verify... any suggestions?
2. Given that this is actually the problem, can anyone suggest an easy-to-use/deploy hosting that also allow easy VPN configuration? I think Heroku doesn't give you to do that unless you have an enterprise account

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that Amazon is very good at blocking IPs. It is very likely that they already blacklisted IPs of cloud services like Heroku, Azure, etc... Previously I have observed services like Cloudflare, Akamai etc... blacklisting these known IPs.

In this scenario Rotating proxies could help you to avoid getting blocked.